# Proof about the dimension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

In Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra and Its Applications (4th edition), he states:

> If $v_1,...,v_m$ and $w_1,...,w_n$ are both bases for the same vector space, then m=n. The number of vectors is the same

He then goes onto the proof of this theorem:

He expresses the vectors $w_1,...,w_n$ as a combination of $v_1,...,v_n$:

$W=\begin{bmatrix} &&&\\w_1 & w_2 & ... & w_n\\&&&\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}&&\\v_1 & ... & v_m\\&&\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&&&&&\\\vdots&&&&&\\a_{m1}&&&&& \end{bmatrix}=VA$

Here, $A$ is a $m$ by $n$ matrix, so it must have a nonzero solution to $Ax=0$. Therefore, $W$ and $VA$ is multiplied by this nonzero solution:

$VAx=0=Wx$

Hence, the vectors $w_1,...,w_n$ are dependent and cannot be a basis.

Similarly when $m>n$, the same steps can be applied and there will also be a contradiction. So $m=n$ to avoid any contradiction.

However, when $A$ is a non-invertible matrix (where $A$ is $m$ by $n, \ m=n$), that also means that there will be a nonzero solution.

Do we just assume that $A$ will always be invertible when it is a square matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an assumption. You've proved that $A$ is square; you could go on and prove it's invertible. The same argument applies: if $Ax=0$ for some nonzero $x$ then $Wx=0$, which is a contradiction. So $Ax$ must be nonzero for all nonzero $x$, which means $A$ must be invertible.

This wasn't relevant to the statement being proved, which is why it wasn't mentioned, but it's certainly a worthwhile thing to know.